# Twitter Academic Research with japanese language

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

This is my first question. I would like to seek your advice on this matter.<(_ _)>

I got a Twitter Academic Research account. To get the tweets of a specific user, Using [official sample code](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Full-Archive-Search/full-archive-search.py) as a reference, I made the "param" as follows.

```html
query_params = {'query': '(from:jtwfihT7bFRPzEx -is:retweet)','lang': 'ja', 'tweet.fields': 'author_id'}
```

But if I specify "lang" as an argument to the "query" parameter, I get the following error.

```html
Exception: (400, '{"errors":[{"parameters":{"lang":["ja"]},"message":"The query parameter [lang] is not one of [query,start_time,end_time,since_id,until_id,max_results,next_token,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}')
```

Does Twitter Academic Research still not support Japanese?

Off topic, I was using Standard API version 1.1 to get tweets, but does Academic Account work with API v1.1?

Comment: the `lang` parameter should probably be inside the query string

Comment: I see.Thanks to you, I can solve this problem! Thank you very much<(_ _)>